# How to define inner class member in derived class?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        class B{
            public:
                void fun1();
        };
};

class C:public A{
    public:
        B::fun1(){ // This line gives Error:can not define member function B::fun1() in C

        }       
};
int main(){
    C ob;
    return 0;
}
```

there is any way to define inner class member in derived class ?
What is the reason behind this error ?

Comment: Essentially an inner class in an ordinary class (with a scope in the enclosing class and access (visibility) to all members of the enclosing class). Same error: `struct X { void f(); }; struct Y { void X::f() {} };`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to define the function within a different class scope than the one it was declared in.  For example, consider this expanded version of your code:

```
class A{
    public:
        class B{
            public:
                void fun1();
                void fun2();
        };

        void fun3();

        void B::fun2() {} // Error.
};

class C:public A{
    public:
        void B::fun1() {} // Error.
        void A::fun3() {} // Error.
};
```

All three errors will give the same type of error message, "`Can not define member function X::Y() in Z`".

---

To solve this, if `A::B::fun1()` and `C::B::fun1()` need to have different implementations, you can derive from the nested class, as well.

```
class A {
  public:
    class AB_ {
      public:
        virtual void fun1();
    };

    typedef AB_ B;
};
void A::AB_::fun1() {}

class C : public A {
  public:
    class CB_ : public A::AB_ {
        void fun1() override;
    };

    typedef CB_ B;
};
void C::CB_::fun1() {}
```

In this case, you can use `B` externally to access the most-derived version of the nested class, or use `A::AB_` or `C::CB_` directly.  Similarly, you could write something like this:

```
class A {
    class AB_ {
      public:
        virtual void fun1();
    } b;

  public:
    typedef AB_ B;

    virtual B& getB() { return b; }
};
void A::AB_::fun1() {}

class C : public A {
    // Note the use of the typedef, instead of the actual type name.
    class CB_ : public A::B {
        void fun1() override;
    } cb;

  public:
    typedef CB_ B;

    // Note the use of the typedef, instead of the actual type name.
    A::B& getB() override { return cb; }
};
void C::CB_::fun1() {}
```

In this case, `C` internally uses `A`'s typedef, while simultaneously replacing it; due to this, uses of `A`'s typedef are made explicit, as `A::B` instead of `B`.  Due to the typedefs, the name `B` will mean either `A::AB_` or `C::CB_`, when used as `A::B` or `C::B`, respectively.

```
// If given the above...

int main() {
    std::cout << "A::B: " << typeid(A::B).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C::B: " << typeid(C::B).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The output will be:

```
// GCC:
A::B: N1A3AB_E
C::B: N1C3CB_E

// MSVC:
A::B: class A::AB_
C::B: class C::CB_
```